# how to write kafka to kafka sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i was trying for kafka mirror. And i found this open source [Comcast]: https://github.com/Comcast/MirrorTool-for-Kafka-Connect and it is successfully working when retrieving data form source kafka topic and writing it to destination kafka topic. now i need to sink from destination kafka topic and writing it to source kafka. How can i do that please suggest references.

i wrote **kafkaSinkTask** file. and inside put method i am able to get topics from destination kafka. so i don't know how to write this topics to source kfafa

```
    @Override
    public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {
        if (records.isEmpty()) {
              return;
            }
            final SinkRecord first = records.iterator().next();
            final int recordsCount = records.size();
            logger.info(
                "Received {} records. First record kafka coordinates:({}-{}-{}).
                + "database...",
                recordsCount, first.topic(), first.kafkaPartition(), first.kafkaOffset()
            );  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> now i need to sink from destination kafka topic and writing it to source kafka

Can you not just flip the source and destination servers in your config file? Connect should generally consume from the remote cluster and produce to a local one (given two data centers or geographically separated networks), and store the consumed offsets at the destination in the Connect offsets topic, thus it being a source connector.

You could also try MirrorMaker 2.0 instead - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0

Comment: i need to use only one config file like jdbc source connector.

Comment: Jdbc connector also has 2 config files. One to start connect server and the other to start the connector. As mentioned, MirrorMaker2, just released in Kafka 2.4, has the ability to switch clusters in one file. But also mentioned, there's valid reasons for having a source connector, and it determines if/how duplicate offsets are handled

Comment: you mean. by only one config file i can perform both sink and source task

Comment: No MirrorMaker2 is still a source connector type https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorSourceConnector.java#L62 But it can be used to define both source and destination clusters in one config file